# Why does an intersection of all inductive sets comprise natural numbers?

Tags: natural-numbers

I suppose we cannot say "Let natural numbers be $1, 1+1, 1+1+1, \dots$", but I fail to put into words why we can't. What's the reason to define natural numbers as an intersection of inductive sets? If we could define it as I wrote above, we wouldn't be troubled with questions like "Is there a natural number between $1$ and $2$?"

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "..."?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean we proceed by adding $1$ to the previous number, in question the next will be $1+1+1+1$ and so on

Comment: @AlexanderVronsky What you described is precisely an inductive definition of natural numbers...

Comment: @5xum True. Then why we trouble ourselves with an intersection of all inductive sets instead of specifying the one that matters?

Comment: @AlexanderVronsky Well, provided that you have an axiom that says that there is an inductive set (i.e. a set $s$ such that $1\in s\land \forall z, (z\notin s\lor z+1\in s )$ ), you *are* specifying the one that matters: $x\in \Bbb N\Leftrightarrow (\forall y, (\neg\text{Inductive}(y)\lor x\in y))$. If you haven't got that axiom, then the probem is that (provided giving a set-theoretical meaning to $1$ and $y+1$) you cannot prove that there is a set $X$ such that $1\in X\land\forall y,(y\notin X\lor y+1\in X)$.

Comment: @AlexanderVronsky We add finite sums of the form $\sum 1$ to our candidate set.  And doing that any finite number of times is fine, we get a set. You might protest with "well, just add such elements indefinitely". Fair enough, but how do you know that this process yields a set? An infinite set, at that. You have to assume it does, there is no other way.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio okay, I guess I understand. Thank you

Comment: @AlvinL Also true, thank you very much!